# Check sessions when redirecting pages in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, session-state

Here's the scenario: Page 1 has a text box that, if filled, will be the name of the session.
It also has a button that will take you to Page 2 (when clicked).

Page 2 has a button as well that simply redirects you back to Page 1.
But now, how do I show the session name in Page 1's textbox?

I don't think I can use the Page_Load function as that'll "interfere" when you first visit Page 1.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Page1Button_Click ....
{
    Session["Text"] = this.textbox.Text;
    Response.Redirect ....
}

Page1_Load ...
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
         this.textBox.Text = Session["Text"] != null ? Session["Text"].ToString() : "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, Akram!
That worked exactly the way I wanted it to!
And I've also learned something new... I didn't know about the IsPostBack. Yes, call me a newb...

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this in page load, if I'm understanding your question.

```
textBox.Text = Session["myvalue"] != null ? Session["myvalue"].ToString() : "";
```

Answer (score 1):

They are different pages, so they should have different Page_Load events.

The first time they post on Page 1, store the value they entered in the session.  Then, any other time you are on Page 1, just look in the session to see if that value is stored.  If it is, display it.